# iScroll is firing multiple clicks on an LI element

Tags: html-lists, iscroll

I've implemented iScroll into a web page, intended for a smartphone. I haven't tried this yet in an emulator so I don't know if this is just a PC problem.

The scroller contains a UL.  Each LI is marked with an onclick event handler:

```
$("li.myitem").click(showItemDetails);

...

function showItemDetails() ...
```

When I implemented this prior to using iScroll, if I click ONCE on a LI I get one call to my click handler (which opens another view window).  After using iScroll I have two bad behaviors.

- When scrolling around, sometimes iScroll thinks that I want to click on something.  That is, iScroll is working something like an "onmouseup" event.
- When clicking on an event, whether intentionally or not, iScroll is generating 10, 20 and even 30 events (or event threads) for that one place that a single event is intentioned for.  I traced it, and all of the events are coming from the same LI item.  This occurs just as badly if I change the click handler to a double-click handler (dblclick()).

In the immediate, I'm reduced to putting in a gatekeeper, a flag saying "I'm already busy with an event, go away".  I could also change the interface to have the user click (select) an LI and then click on a separate button to see the details.

But I'm concerned about what iScroll is doing.

Any ideas?  Need to see code?  I can't put on the whole app (a thousand lines long, after comments), but I can show decent snips.  But I'm hoping that this is an "oh, yeah" moment and someone tells me a known story.